# Returning the TOP 20 ProductCodes (SKUs) in a Query using TOP 20 along with SUM

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an `Orders` and an `OrderDetails` table. I am trying to get the TOP 20 selling ProductCodes by summing the quantity (`QTY`) of each `ProductCode` sold. I am having problems getting the query correct. At first, I was able to get the query to work using Count in place of SUM, but that was giving false results. Because you see below that would return BBB (4 units) as the winner, but actually we sold more of AAA (6 units).

Example data:

`Orders` table

| ID | Rep | ShipDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amazon | 8/29/2022 |

OrderDetails table

| ProductCode | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 1 |
| BBB | 1 |
| BBB | 1 |
| BBB | 1 |
| BBB | 1 |
| CCC | 3 |
| AAA | 2 |
| AAA | 3 |

Below is my latest attempt. I thought I was getting close, but now I get prompted to enter a value for `SumOfQty` whenever I run the query. The `OrderDetails.Packaging` column is an additional column I would like to include in the output of the query, but not essential to getting the correct results.  It seems like Access does not like an alias in the GROUP BY and ORDER BY.

```
SELECT TOP 20 
    SUM(OrderDetails.QTY) AS SumOfQTY, 
    OrderDetails.ProductCode, OrderDetails.Packaging
FROM 
    Orders 
LEFT JOIN 
    OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
WHERE 
    (((Orders.ShipDate) BETWEEN #8/29/2022# AND #9/1/2022#) 
     AND ((Orders.Rep)="Amazon"))
GROUP BY 
    SumOfQTY, OrderDetails.ProductCode, OrderDetails.Packaging
ORDER BY 
    SumOfQTY DESC;
```

Thank you in advance,
Ira

Comment: 1. You cannot Group By something you are summing; take out SumOfQTY from Group By clause.  2. Change Order By from SumOfQTY to Sum(OrderDetails.QTY) DESC and you should be OK.

Comment: Thank you marc_s for editing my question and showing me how to post properly.